# htaccess forwarding some subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm forwarding a subdomain like this (which turns sub.example.com into example.com/subdomain/sub)

```
# the rewrite that forwards sub-domains as guide 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}:9081/subdomain/%1/$1 [P,QSA,NE]
```

Which works well, however breaks all the relative links to the CSS/JS files.

I was hoping I could put in another rule, which stops the forwarding of any example.com/resources requests regardless of the subdomain, i.e.

```
RewriteRule ^resources\/$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}:9081/resources/$1 [QSA,P,L]
```

is currently forwarding to example.com/subdomain/resources, when I want it to forward to example.com/resources.

Any idea how I can override a rewrite rule for a subdomain on particular subfolders, or is this not possible? Other solution is absolute URLs in the CSS/JS which I'd hope to avoid.

Thanks

Comment: Normally you would use mod_proxy's `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` for this. Success will depend on the application being proxied however (regardless of whether you use mod_proxy or mod_rewrite). Neither way will edit the response body, only the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding a condition:

```
# the rewrite that forwards sub-domains as guide 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|css)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}:9081/subdomain/%1/$1 [P,QSA,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it broke the rewrite so all this traffic redirects to example.com with broken CSS/JS. I tried adding a  ^, so  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^\.(js|css)$ [NC], and this enabled the CSS/JS to work, but still directs this traffic to example.com

So close, but not quite there. Any ideas how to change that condition so it redirects to the page, and the CSS/JS are still found!?

Comment: @user5839 your change broke the rule and is probably using your old site. Or do you have any JavaScript or CSS that are like `http://domain:9081.css`? `^\.(js|css)$` start and ends with, in this specific case it would look for URL's that are `domain.com.css` which of course would never match.

Comment: Thanks. Now is this condition saying everything but js/css files, or does it include js/css files? I'm wanting it to exclude any cs/css requests.

Comment: @user5839 Sorry, I meant to have a `!` in there. Yeah, you want to *exclude* the css/js stuff.